# trigger.new alternative to record triggered flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I am facing issues with record triggered flow.

For triggers, when we update the bulk or collection of records ( update [select id from opportunity limit 5] ), we get them in trigger.new list which I would process them further. But in the flow I am not that list, only I am getting is $Record.objectid. that means only one record.

[image: Input flow]

That means my flow will only run for 1 record at a time, what if I update 200 records together or do a dataloader operation with batch size 200. I have called a apex action in my flow and it only works for first record. You can see in the debug below, the lines of debug are not repeated it only comes for first record and when I update one record at a time, it works fine.

[image: Flow]

**I get debug logs only once and the calculation only happens for first record and other remain untouched.**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

> You don't need to worry about the limit here. The flow takes care of
> it behind the scenes. It is processed in such a way that it will store
> all records to update in one list and then it will update all at once.

For more information, you can visit this link - [Flow Bulkification](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5)